# Floating of text-boxes

Tags: html, css, floating

I have a picture with some text surrounding it. The "problem" is responsive design. Here are 3 scenarios separated by the grey vertical line:

[image: these are the images of it]

I currently have scenario 1. But it looks awkward if only a single word is moved to the first line with full width.

Is there a possibility to put the text in some "protected box" which prevents the text from getting ripped apart? The result should look like scenario 2. For sure I could do it using a table with 2 columns, but I want the text to get aligned like in scenario 3 if there is not enough space.

How to do it with html/css only (without javascript)? I need it for a Joomla Homepage.

Comment: what you tried sofar..post your code / create a demo?

Comment: not much to do. you can use "margin-bottom" for IMG which will let you make left "left column" higher. If you at the same time use PHP you can count words or characters (i.e. strlen() function) and decide when to use addition margin-bottom or not. for example add the margin-bottom only if text is shorten than 200 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this many ways, and since you obviously started with `float`, here is how to with `float`.

```css
.first {
  float: left;
}
.second {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/100" alt="">
</div>

<div class="second">
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
</div>
```

And here is how to with `display: inline-block`, which I also would recommend instead of `float`

```css
.first {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.second {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/100" alt="">
</div>

<div class="second">
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
  Here is some text<br>
</div>
```

And an even better way might be `flex`, though it is not supported by older browser, but today that shouldn't be a big issue

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.first {
  flex: 0;
}
.second {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/100" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="second">
    Here is some text 
    Here is some text 
    Here is some text 
    Here is some text 
    Here is some text 
    Here is some text 
    Here is some text<br>
    Here is some text<br>
    Here is some text<br>
    Here is some text<br>
    Here is some text<br>
    Here is some text<br>
    Here is some text<br>
    Here is some text<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you would prefer 'inline-block' instead of 'float' ?

Comment: @yuv60 Because OP asks for how to lay out 2 columns instead of having a text float around an image, and `float` is not meant for layout but `inline-block` is.

Comment: Thank you LGSon for your detailed and comprehensive answer. I went with option 3. This one is quite easy and clean to implement and does exactly what I want. I futhermore like the possibility with the min-width option.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create two columns with divs like this

```
<div class="column">
  <img />
</div>
<div>
  Here put your text
</div class="column">
```

Your basic style should generate the columns:

```
.column {
    width:50;
    float: left;
 }
```

And add a media query for when there's not enough space:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as follows

```
<div class="first-box">
  <img /> <!-- Image -->
</div>

<div class="second-box">
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
</div>
```

Here you have the two columns separated into two different divs

Next : The Css

```
.first-box{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}


.first-box img{
  width: 100%;
}


.second-box{
  width:50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

What are we doing here is separating content into two different divs and giving them a 50% width each meaning that they will take half of the whole window each which is 100%; and then we are floating them to the left so that they can stick to / near each other and not fall under each other. Since we want the image to take up the whole div we used a css style on .first-box img giving it a 100% width to stretch to fit.

{{ Note: I used background-color on the second div for the sake of the example to show a background colour }}

Find JSFiddle here : [Click here for Example](https://jsfiddle.net/murb20kh/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Eric. But keeping the image and the text beside each other is not what I intended. I actually DO want, to have one below the other iff the screen width is too small.